# why do "ls -l /dev" and "/bin/ls -l /dev" have differents output? MacOSX

Tags: macos, ls

So i was given this C assignment in which i have to to reproduce the ls command.
Everything is going fine but i have this one problem that i can't manage to understand.

When using ls -l on /dev the output gives me something like this :

```
"ls -l /dev"
...
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root    wheel                     0 Dec 17 15:55 fd
crw-r--r--  1 root    wheel                 13, 0 Dec 17 15:55 fsevents
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel                21, 17 Dec 17 15:55 io8log  <<notice these lines
cr--r--r--  1 root    wheel                21, 14 Dec 17 15:55 io8logmt  <<notice these lines 
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel                21, 15 Dec 17 22:09 io8logtemp  <<notice these lines
crw-------  1 root    wheel                  6, 0 Dec 17 15:55 klog
...
```

but then :

```
"/bin/ls -l /dev":
...
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root    wheel                 0 Dec 17 15:55 fd
crw-r--r--  1 root    wheel           13,   0 Dec 17 15:55 fsevents
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel           21,  15 Dec 17 15:55 io8log  << see how the minor has changed?
cr--r--r--  1 root    wheel           21,  16 Dec 17 15:55 io8logmt << same here
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel           21,  17 Dec 17 22:35 io8logtemp << and here too
crw-------  1 root    wheel            6,   0 Dec 17 15:55 klog
...
```

How come the minor number is changed for these three lines? Aren't ls and /bin/ls the same? Isn't ls just an "alias" for /bin/ls or does this add/remove "options" to the command?

Also (even though this is not the exact same problem), 
how come minor numbers for these files comes out in hex? It doesn't even match the minor number i'm getting from them

```
"ls -l /dev":
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel           33, 0x00000ac7 Dec 17 15:55 autofs_homedirmounter
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel           32, 0x00000ac7 Dec 17 15:55 autofs_notrigger
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel           31, 0x00001581 Dec 17 15:55 autofs_nowait

mine :   
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel              33, 2722 Dec 17 15:55 autofs_homedirmounter
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel              32, 2722 Dec 17 15:55 autofs_notrigger
crw-rw-rw-  1 root    wheel              31, 5198 Dec 17 15:55 autofs_nowait
```

all the other minor/major numbers correspond when calling  either ls, /bin/ls or my program just these lines are different.

If anyone has hints, thanks a lot :)

edit : 
This is the result of the command by zwol :

```
/dev/io8log 1500000f
/dev/io8logmt   15000010
/dev/io8logtemp 15000011
/dev/klog   6000000
/dev/autofs 16000000
/dev/autofs_control 22000000
/dev/autofs_homedirmounter  21000ae5
/dev/autofs_notrigger   20000ae5
/dev/autofs_nowait  1f00174b
```

when calling it twice the numbers varies for all io8 dirs and autofs dirs (except autofs_control) which seems to match the behaviour of ls

Comment: you can test if you're running the same command with `which ls` and `alias ls`

Comment: and `type ls`...

Comment: It is not a difference between `ls` and `/bin/ls`. Repeated executions of the `ls` command show varying minor numbers. I suspect `io8log` is some special device associated with the executing process.

Comment: As an independent cross-check, please run `perl -e 'printf("%s\t%x\n", $_, (stat($_))[6]) for @ARGV' /dev/io8* /dev/klog /dev/autofs*` and post the _complete and unedited_ output. (Type that command _exactly as shown_, except that there isn't supposed to be a line break in the middle.  It will print a hexadecimal number for each device node that somehow encodes both the major and minor numbers -- unfortunately Perl doesn't bundle decoding routines.)

Comment: Yep i just noticed the differences between each call but it only applies to the autofs_ dirs. The io8XXX directories however remain unchanged. i will try that perl command right away

Comment: also noticed that "ls" was alias to ls -g and suppressed it. Both ls and /bin/ls now prints the same results, which makes even less sense now for me is this : How does the colour formatting option affects this?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Mac OS and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: okay my bad, i guess you're right.

Comment: Do you get a difference for `/dev/dtrace` too?  To my considerable surprise, I got results equivalent to yours (plus a difference on `dtrace`).

Comment: yup, I also have different minor number when calling ls multiple times on /dev/dtrace too, seems like those number change either constantly or when trying to access them, it's a shame i can't find more info about this though ^^